# How to generate matrices which satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

Let's consider square matrix

[image]

(n is a dimension of the matrix E and fixed (for example n = 4 or n=5)). Matrix entries
 [image: a_{ij}] satisfy following conditions:

[image]

[image]

The task is to generate all matrices E. My question is how to do that? Is there any common approach or algorithm? Is that even possible? What to start with?

Comment: What is the dimension of your matrices? `n * n`?

Comment: Yes. It is n * n. We are considering that matrices for fixed dimension, for example n = 4 and generating them.

Comment: It is useful to consider matrix size and element range separately. Look at the matrices `E(n,k)` of dimension `n` with elements that range in `0..k` that satisfy your condition. Suppose you can generate all of them. Now what do you need to generate all of `E(n+1,k)`?

Comment: Sorry @svick. I was editing the post.

Comment: This smells like homework. I doubt there is a common approach. Everything is possible. This problem seems interesting but not sure how to help you without solving it for you. You can start by writing down all such matrices for n=3.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for you response. But actually there is no need to consider that

Comment: @fsw thank you. But it is not homework. It is my problem that I faced during my research.

Comment: Of course there's no need to consider anything if you can solve the problem without it.

Comment: The only matrices that satisfy these conditions are Zero Matrices.  Any other matrix will violate one of the two constraints because `a(0,0) = 0` and `a(1,1) = 0`, but `a(0,0) + a(1,1)` can only be `>= 0`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: which condition says something about `a(0,0) + a(1,1)`?

Comment: @n.m. Oops, I see now.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava I'm confused... Why did you unaccept the answer?  You have to be kidding me.

Comment: @TimothyShields cause it's not correct I wrote the program and it didn't work. Also now trying to find example against it, sorry.

Comment: @ArtyMathJava "I wrote the program and it didn't work.". Your program is incorrect, not the answer.  You can't refute a proof by saying your attempt to use it in an implementation doesn't work.  If it "doesn't work" for some N, you should be able to use that as a counterexample to show that one of my proofs is wrong.  Otherwise you're just unfairly blaming me for your own error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Naive solution

A naive solution to consider is to generate every possible `n`-by-`n` matrix `E` where each component is a nonnegative integer no greater than `n`, then take from those only the matrices that satisfy the additional constraints. What would be the complexity of that?

Each component can take on `n + 1` values, and there are `n^2` components, so there are `O((n+1)^(n^2))` candidate matrices. That has an **insanely high growth rate**.

Link: [WolframAlpha analysis of `(n+1)^(n^2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n%2B1%29%5E%28n%5E2%29)

I think it's safe to safe that this not a feasible approach.

## Better solution

A better solution follows. It involves a lot of math.

Let `S` be the set of all matrices `E` that satisfy your requirements. Let `N = {1, 2, ..., n}`.

**Definitions:**

- Let a ***metric*** on `N` to have the usual definition, except with the requirement of symmetry omitted.
- Let `I` and `J` partition the set `N`. Let `D(I,J)` be the `n` x `n` matrix that has `D_ij = 1` when `i` is in `I` and `j` is in `J`, and `D_ij = 0` otherwise.
- Let `A` and `B` be in `S`. Then `A` is ***adjacent*** to `B` if and only if there exist `I` and `J` partitioning `N` such that `A + D(I,J) = B`.

  We say `A` and `B` are ***adjacent*** if and only if `A` is adjacent to `B` or `B` is adjacent to `A`.
- Two matrices `A` and `B` in `S` are ***path-connected*** if and only if there exists a sequence of adjacent elements of `S` between them.
- Let the function `M(E)` denote the sum of the elements of matrix `E`.

**Lemma 1:**
`E = D(I,J)` is a metric on `N`.

> **Proof:**
>   This is a trivial statement except for the case of an edge going from `I` to `J`. Let `i` be in `I` and `j` be in `J`. Then `E_ij = 1` by definition of `D(I,J)`. Let `k` be in `N`. If `k` is in `I`, then `E_ik = 0` and `E_kj = 1`, so `E_ik + E_kj >= E_ij`. If `k` is in `J`, then `E_ik = 1` and `E_kj = 0`, so `E_ij + E_kj >= E_ij`.

**Lemma 2:**
Let `E` be in `S` such that `E != zeros(n,n)`. Then there exist `I` and `J` partitioning `N` such that `E' = E - D(I,J)` is in `S` with `M(E') < M(E)`.

> **Proof:**
>   Let `(i,j)` be such that `E_ij > 0`. Let `I` be the subset of `N` that can be reached from `i` by a directed path of cost `0`. `I` cannot be empty, because `i` is in `I`. `I` cannot be `N`, because `j` is not in `I`. This is because `E` satisfies the triangle inequality and `E_ij > 0`.
>
> Let `J = N - I`. Then `I` and `J` are both nonempty and partition `N`. By the definition of `I`, there does not exist any `(x,y)` such that `E_xy = 0` and `x` is in `I` and `y` is in `J`. Therefore `E_xy >= 1` for all `x` in `I` and `y` in `J`.
>
> Thus `E' = E - D(I,J) >= 0`. That `M(E') < M(E)` is obvious, because all we have done is subtract from elements of `E` to get `E'`. Now, since `E` is a metric on `N` and `D(I,J)` is a metric on `N` (by **Lemma 1**) and `E >= D(I,J)`, we have `E'` is a metric on `N`. Therefore `E'` is in `S`.

**Theorem:**
Let `E` be in `S`. Then `E` and `zeros(n,n)` are path-connected.

> **Proof (by induction):**
>   If `E = zeros(n,n)`, then the statement is trivial.
>
> Suppose `E != zeros(n,n)`. Let `M(E)` be the sum of the values in `E`. Then, by induction, we can assume that the statement is true for any matrix `E'` having `M(E') < M(E)`.
>
> Since `E != zeros(n,n)`, by **Lemma 2** we have some `E'` in `S` such that `M(E') < M(E)`. Then by the inductive hypothesis `E'` is path-connected to `zeros(n,n)`. Therefore `E` is path-connected to `zeros(n,n)`.

**Corollary:**
The set `S` is path-connected.

> **Proof:**
>   Let `A` and `B` be in `S`. By the **Theorem**, `A` and `B` are both path-connected to `zeros(n,n)`. Therefore `A` is path-connected to `B`.

## Algorithm

The **Corollary** tells us that everything in `S` is path-connected. So an effective way to discover all of the elements of `S` is to perform a breadth-first search over the graph defined by the following.

- The elements of `S` are the nodes of the graph
- Nodes of the graph are connected by an edge if and only if they are adjacent

Given a node `E`, you can find all of the (potentially) unvisited neighbors of `E` by simply enumerating all of the possible matrices `D(I,J)` (of which there are `2^n`) and generating `E' = E + D(I,J)` for each. Enumerating the `D(I,J)` should be relatively straightforward (there is one for every possible subset `I` of `D`, except for the empty set and `D`).

Note that, in the preceding paragraph, `E` and `D(I,J)` are both metrics on `N`. So when you generate `E' = E + D(I,J)`, **you don't have to check that it satisfies the triangle inequality** - `E'` is the sum of two metrics, so it is a metric. To check that `E'` is in `S`, all you have to do is verify that the maximum element in `E'` does not exceed `n`.

You can start the breadth-first search from any element of `S` and be guaranteed that you won't miss any of `S`.  So you can start the search with `zeros(n,n)`.

---

Be aware that the cardinality of the set `S` grows extremely fast as `n` increases, so computing the entire set `S` will only be tractable for small `n`.